# Selector for last column in floating divs

Tags: css-float

Suppose that I have 12 elements with `width: 25%; float: left;` it'll be like this:

```
---------
|a|b|c|d|
---------
|e|f|g|h|
---------
|i|j|k|l|
---------
```

I have added `overflow: visible;` to these divs and a div inside each of these divs which will expand on hover. It's working alright. The problem is I want it to expand to right for all the divs except `d`, `h` and `l` for which it should expand to left. I wonder if it's possible to do it without javascript. Is there any css selector that can select `d`, `h` and `l` (consider that it's responsive and it's not always 4 divs per row. It may be 10 or 2 rows per row.) Or maybe there's another solution for this selective expansion problem without above mentioned selector.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: @CBroe nth-child doesn't help, as I said size of rows is unknown and subject to change.

Comment: Well, in what way is it responsive? If the number of elements per rows is determined by assigning specific widths in media queries at certain breakpoints, then you can use nth-child with different values in those.

Comment: No unfortunately it's not the case, it's subject to change not just by window's width, so using breakpoints doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **flexbox** solution to this. Choose better values to achive the desired output.

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-around;
}
li{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #8056ff;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 40px;
  transition: flex-basis 1s;
}
li:hover{
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
  <li>h</li>
  <li>i</li>
  <li>j</li>
  <li>k</li>
  <li>l</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, while your solution is awesome, but it doesn't solve my problem. I wasn't clear enough in the question. I don't want the expanding elements to change size of other elements. It should work like a popup covering items behind it. It's simple to achieve this using position: absolute on the nested divs and position: relative in items. But the problem is with the last column. It should expand to left unlike others. If there were a selector for last column it'd be done easily.